# Unable to Download Application on iPad iOS 5.1.1?

Tags: ipad

i have 2 application (app' A. and app' B.)
i distribute by "for enterprise"

i have 3 ipad
- 2 ipad use ios 5.1
- 1 ipad use ios 5.1.1

i have web server run iis and i upload .ipa and .plist to web server
and create like for download app' A and app' B on web page

i use ipad (ios 5.1) download and install app A and B it's ok no any ploblem

when i use ipad (ios 5.1.1) download and install app A it's ok no any ploblem
BUT when i download and install app B on ipad alert "Unable to Download Application"

how i can fix it

thank you

ps1. app A and B same config'
ps2. sorry for my english skills.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to distribute your application with **In House** or **Ad Hoc** Certificate ? If you don't know the difference, you can see [this](http://blog.appaloosa-store.com/3-things-to-know-to-distribute-your-ios-apps) article to understand better how you can distribute your apps.

Your problem seem to be a known problem : articles on techplex, techiehq...

If you are using **Ad Hoc** certificates, you should have provisioned UDIDs of authorized devices in your Provisioning Profil. Are you sure you have provisioned your iPad with 5.1.1 in this profile ?

If you are using **In House** certificates, you are not the one to have this problem. It seems to be a problem with iOS 5.1.1. Some possibilites are :

- you are using 3G and not Wifi, and there is a problem during download.
- you are updating your application, and it does not work.
- you have an iOS 5.1.1 bug

I am working on [this](http://www.appaloosa-store.com). You can create a free account, and try to distribute your application to your devices with this service. You will access to informations such as the kind of certificate you use, which devices are referenced.

Please give me more informations :

- In House or Ad Hoc certificates ?
- Does the error appears during the download (progress bar under 2/3) ?
- Do you try to install your app with Wifi or 3G ?

Comment: sorry i wrong ... i set some config in App B to ios 5.0 ... thank for your answer